# AngularJs passing a value to a directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to pass a value to a directive. The directive is used to integrate a jquery plugin [Knob](http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/)

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/Tropicalista/TH87t/93/

I have this code:

```
var App = angular.module('Knob', []);
App.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.number = 24;
})

App.directive('knob', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).knob().val(scope.number); 
        console.log(attrs)
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `knob()` doesn't return the element. Use this instead:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    $(element).val(scope.number).knob();
}
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TH87t/94/

Comment: This works, thanks for the help. But if I want change value with a press on button, I should add $watch to directive? http://jsfiddle.net/Tropicalista/TH87t/96/

Comment: @Tropicalista - That's not how you use `$watch`. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/TH87t/98/

Comment: Oh thanks, I'm a really noob about angular and directive seems too complicated...

Answer (score 2):

I used your question as reference for a fully bi-direction binding. For a working version with angular 1.2.1 see http://jsfiddle.net/sander_van_dam/m5YJu/

```
App.directive('knob', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: { model: '=ngModel' },
        controller: function($scope, $element, $timeout) {
                var el = $($element);
                $scope.$watch('model', function(v) {
                    var el = $($element);
                    el.val(v).trigger('change');
                });
        },

        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs,$ngModel) {
                    var el = $($element);
                    el.val($scope.value).knob(
                        {
                            'change' : function (v) {
                                $scope.$apply(function () {
                                  $ngModel.$setViewValue(v);
                            });
                        }
                        }
                    );
        }
    }

});
```